# UITextbox and UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitextview, uipickerview

I have a the following piece of code:

```
-(IBAction)routePicker
{   
    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 264, 320, 216)]; 
    UIPickerView *thePickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,216)];
    thePickerView.dataSource = self;
    thePickerView.delegate = self;
    [myView addSubview:thePickerView];
    [self.view addSubview:myView];  
}
```

this creates a subview of the UIPickerView, which contains predefined items I added.

At the moment this IBAction is linked to a custom button, so when I click on the button it loads the subview. I want to text box instead of a custom button. So when I click/tap on the text box my UIPickerView should load in the subview.

Regards,
Stephen

Comment: Do you want to be able to edit your text view? If so your picker will likely become hidden by standard keyboard...

Comment: No, I just want to be able to select from the picker and have it fill the textbox with the selection. It doesn't have to be a text maybe a label ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this example from apple

[Date Cell picker](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/DateCell/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008866)